# Where can I find the Add node?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, color

Can somebody please team me where I can find the Blue topped ADD node
it's driving me mad....

I was following a tutorial by Blender guru and he showed a node tree
of a glass hack. cannot recreate it as I cannot locate the node

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: It's a *Math* node set to *Add*

Comment: Thanks so much as a new user just still finding my feet around the interface. 
really appreciate the time you took to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue Add node is a math node. Search Math, click on the result, and this will pop up.